# sending data to flask server with curl

Tags: python, shell, curl, flask

I am sending data from a remote app to my flask webserver on a raspberry pi that manages my home automation. This is done with  an url in the form

> http://192.168.1.212:5000/twi?twitakt=1&b0=24&b1=91&b2=24&b3=91

from my macOS app and works without problems.
I am trying to send aquivalent data with curl from a shell script in the form

> curl --data 'twitakt=1&b0=24&b1=91&b2=24&b3=91' http://192.168.1.212:5000/twi

as I read in many tutorials on the web.
The data does not reach the flask server. I used double quotes, addition of -X POST, splitting in multiple parts with -d "b0=24" -d "b1=91" with no success. The only way to transfer one chunk is to append ?b0=24 to the end of the url. Appending a seccond chunk &b1=91 is ignored.
In the flask template I have

> b0: {{ b0  }}
>
> b1: {{ b1  }}
>
> b2: {{ b2  }}

and in the console I get

b0: 24

b1: None

b2: None

Is it not possible to send date in this way, or is an error in my code?

Comment: Is your server accept `GET` or `POST`. In your example the first method is GET and then you're trying to send POST method in second. I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find another solution than packing all data into one string. That works for me.